# The torque $\bf p \times \bf E$ on a dipole causes it to oscillate about $\bf E .$

Tags: electrostatics

The torque $p \times E$ on a dipole causes it to oscillate about $\bf E.$ Only if there is  dissipative mechanism, $y$?
Why does it not work without it?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context here? It is really vague now.

Comment: If there's dissipation the dipole will eventually settle down and align itself with the field, if there isn't it will oscillate forever.